# Groovy ClassNotFoundException: groovy.swing.factory.groovy$lang$Closure

Tags: eclipse, groovy

In Eclipse I have for some reason since last week a weird error while using Groovy. I never seen this error before and a search shows that I seems to be the only one.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/swing/factory/groovy$lang$Closure
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3427)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:2019)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1518)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1491)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:1341)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.isMethodPresent(ReflectionUtils.java:1242)
```

I have no clue why I get this. I'm not using Swing or Groovy Swing anywhere. It's not JUnit 5 related because I got this also from Guice.

This should be related with Eclipse because if I compile it in Maven it runs fine. Currently I need to do a mvn clean install so that it runs again in Eclipse.

```
Eclipse Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112

Groovy 3.0.14
```

Run in Eclipse. Groovy is added as dependency. It should run without errors.

Comment: I also saw smth similar. I added `groovy-swing` (or whatever it's called) dependency to `testImplementation` and the error gone

Comment: This works. I added groovy-swing to the test dependencies.